# "Open link in new tab" missing in Google Search bar

Tags: google-search

On a Galaxy S4 I9505 with Android 4.2.2, typing something in the Google search bar widget on the home screen opens a browser page with search results. The problem is that you can't open multiple tabs from this page, as no menu opens on long-tapping a link.

As the Google bar on the home page is the fastest way to start a search, is there a way to set it so that it opens results in a different browser, or to enable the "Open in new tab" functionality in search results?

Comment: No, I don't think there is.

Comment: What you describe is different than what I see - when I search from the Google Search bar/widget it displays results in the Google Search app. Once I tap on a result my browser opens and a new tab is created to view the link. (GNex & N7, Stock 4.3)